Is the map from global sections to stalks flat?
Let $k$ be a field, $X$ be an integral algebraic variety over $k$. Let $x\in X$. Then is the natural ring map (taking the stalk) $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ flat? If $X$ is affine, then the map is a localization, which is flat.

Since you scheme is integral, the restriction map to an open affine is injective, so you can view this map as an inclusion into an integral domain followed by localization. I think this mean this has to be a flat morphism, but I can’t work out the details right now.

@Chris Not every inclusion of integral domains is flat.

@MartinBrandenburg, I know but it means we can view this map as localization restricted to subring of an integral domain. I don’t know if this necessarily implies flat off the top of my head, but it seemed like a good way to approach the problem.

@Chris Doesn't change things. If your statement, that for $B \subseteq A$ always $B \to A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is flat would be true, then also $B_{\mathfrak{q}} \to A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ would be flat, where $\mathfrak{q}$ is the contraction of $\mathfrak{p}$ (since the tensor product over $B$ is the same as the tensor product over its localization), and since $\mathfrak{p}$ is arbitrary, $B \subseteq A$ would be flat. So, no, this doesn't work.

Incidentally, this proves that the statement here is equivalent to the condition that  $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \to \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is flat for open affines $U \subseteq X$. I think this is false.

@MartinBrandenburg https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443434/flatness-of-restriction-of-structure-sheaf-over-ring-of-global-sections

What do you want to say with that link? There, $U$ is not affine (and $X$ is affine and not integral).

@MartinBrandenburg I apologize, this was my carelessness in reading the question. I was just trying to indicate that such counterexamples are well-known (despite my link a bad representation of this). Luckily Acrobatic's nice answer below gives another more suited example. Sorry for the confusion.

Counterexample: Let $A=k[x,y]$ and $X=\operatorname{Proj}A[s,t]/(xs-yt)$. $X$ is the blow up of the affine plane at the origin. $X$ is covered by the affine sprectrums of $B=k[x,y,xy^{-1}]$ and $C=k[x,y,x^{-1}y]$. Thus, the global section of $X$ is $C\cap B= A$. $B$ is not flat over $A$ because tensoring $B$ with $\cdot x:A/y \hookrightarrow A/y$ induces the zero morphism. So there exist non-flat points.
